# Accessing Complex xml element in Mulesoft's Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule-el

I have input xml like this and need to map Value of Complexelement2.value to variable "Access" in output only when Complexelement2.name is "AccessLevel" .

```
<main>
    <Complexelement1/>
    <Complexelement2>
        <name>SystemType</name>
        <value>100</value>
    </Complexelement2>
    <Complexelement2>
        <name>AdminId</name>
        <value>606</value>
    </Complexelement2>
    <Complexelement2>
        <name>AccessLevel</name>
        <value>200</value>
    </Complexelement2>
</main>
```

need some suggestion for this conditional traversing for this in Dataweave- Mulesoft.

Comment: 0

down vote

favorite





I have input xml like this and need to map Value of complexelement2.value. to variable "Access" in output only when complexelement2.name is "AccessLevel" .

Comment: Consider adding an example of how you've already tried to solve this issue so we can better address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Dataweave

```
 %dw 1.0
 %output application/xml
 ---

 main: { (payload.main filter ($.name == "AccessLevel") map {
     Complexelement2: {
       name:$.name,
       value:$.value
      }
 }) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using mule xslt transformation

1. Mule xslt transformer using xslt file transform.xslt

   ```
   <mulexml:xslt-transformer mimeType="application/xml" xsl-
   file="src/main/resources/transform.xslt" maxIdleTransformers="2" 
   maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="XSLT"/>
   ```
2. transform.xslt code

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"   
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
   <main>      
   <xsl:copy-of select="/main/Complexelement2[name='AccessLevel']"/>       
   </main>     
   </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
3. Output

   ```
   <main>
   <Complexelement2>         
    <name>AccessLevel</name>         
    <value>200</value>     
   </Complexelement2>
   </main>
   ```